# XMLHttpRequest always gets an empty response, while directly pinging the same url via browser gets the right response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest

Here is my javascript snippet:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
          ...
        } 
      }
    }
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/questions/1';
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
```

this.status is always 0, and this.responseText is always ""

If i ping the url 'http://localhost:3000/questions/1' directly from the browser, i get the correct html back.

FYI, i am pinging a rails server i am running on my machine.

Comment: From what domain are you calling it? Is it `http://localhost:3000` too?

Comment: make sure the host:port is the same as per the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score -1):

I would try replacing `this` with `xhr` in your code. The function declaration will keep the `xhr` variable via the closure. I am not sure what `this` will be when the function is called back.