# How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest in javascript client?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I need to call [OpenMRS REST API](https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/API) from Java script to get data from OpenMRS. Below is my java script code:

```
    function myfunction(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();         

    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8081/openmrs-standalone/ws/rest/v1/person?q=John Smith", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46QWRtaW4xMjM");
    xhr.send(null); 
            alert(xhr.responseXml);
    }
```

When I call the given url from browser with credentials I get the XML response as shown below:

```
<object>
    <results>
        <person>
            <uuid>007037a0-0500-11e3-8ffd-0800200c9a66</uuid>
            <display>John Smith</display>
            <links>
                <link>
                    <rel>self</rel>
                        <uri>
                            NEED-TO-CONFIGURE/ws/rest/v1/person/007037a0-0500-11e3-8ffd-0800200c9a66
                        </uri>
                </link>
            </links>
        </person>
    </results>
</object>
```

But the problem is, the javascript alert message comes with value "undefined". If I analyze the network traffic by Firebug, the HTML tab shows a 200 OK success message but XHR tab shows "URL: 0 request, Size: 0B" message. Same thing can be checked in Firefox web console also that the response is not coming. I found a somewhat similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498011/xmlhttprequest-always-gets-an-empty-response-while-directly-pinging-the-same-ur?rq=1) but no solution. How can I get the XML response that is sent back by the Server as I get while calling the URL directly from browser?

**Updated Code:**

```
function myfunction(){

        function reqListener () {
        console.log(this.responseXml);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();     
            xhr.onload = reqListener;

    xhr.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false); 

    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8081/openmrs-standalone/ws/rest/v1/person?q=John Smith", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46QWRtaW4xMjM");

function updateProgress (oEvent) {
      if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;
        // ...
      } else {
        // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
      }
    }

    function transferComplete(evt) {
      alert("The transfer is complete.");
    }

    function transferFailed(evt) {
      alert("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
    }

    function transferCanceled(evt) {
      alert("The transfer has been canceled by the user.");
    }

    xhr.send(null); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xhr.readyState==4)
        {
            alert("State: "+xhr.readyState+" and Status: "+xhr.status+" and Response: "+xhr.responseXml);
        }
      }

    }
```

Alert from `onreadystatechange` function shows `State: 4 and Status: 0 and Response:Undefined`. So, `Status` is not coming as 200 and `Response` is coming as undefined.

Comment: Look at some more examples, and note that they all use the `readyState `event, and listen for the number `4`, there's a reson for that.

Comment: @adeneo I have updated the code above with onreadystatechange and the alert box is showing status as 0 and responseText as blank. Could you please help me to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code do following change and see if that resolves your issue with undefined:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        alert("State: " + xhr.readyState + " and Status: " + xhr.status  
              + " and Response: " + xhr.responseXML);
    }
  }
}
```

Please NOTE **`xhr.responseXML`** as compared to **`xhr.responseXml`** in your code.